# Proxy issue in selenium chrome driver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have installed selenium grid 4 in my internal network via helm. I wish to connect to my internal staging server. Now while loading it requires some external js/css resource to be loaded. Hence I have used a proxy.

Problem without the proxy: the page is not getting loaded properly. And in the end I get gateway timeout http 504.

Problem with the proxy: the proxy is created to connect to external world it has no connection to the internal stg dev servers. Here I get net.ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION failed error. (Http 403).

I tried using the proxy.setsslProxy and proxy.setnoProxy (list of my internal server fqdn). But looks like it is not working printing the proxy only gives me http and ssl components.

Please let me know the best practice to resolve the issue

Comment: Why does loading external js/css resources require a proxy?  Can you just modify a hosts file?  Is this a domain name issue?

Comment: I have resolved the issue by adding application domain to the no proxy list. Earlier I was only adding the pod ip cidrs. So I have set the sslproxy to download the resources and no proxy to bypass.